# fscanf input with floats

Tags: c, scanf

I'm reading from a text file which contains:

```
Mary 55334422 24.90 56.6 45.68
```

and am reading it in:

```
....char name[20]; int num; double worked; double rate; double total;....

fscanf(fp, "%s %d %f %f %f\n", name, &num, &worked, &rate, &total);
```

I'm getting the name and the integer fine, but the floating point numbers come out something like -9522999990000000000000000000.00

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the [format for a double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#Format_string_specifications): `%lf`, rather than that for a float `%f`... or change to floats instead of doubles.

Answer (score 5):

Try `lf` instead of `f` to parse into double variables:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %d %lf %lf %lf\n", name, &num, &worked, &rate, &total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your doubles to floats, or change your format to %lf